# How do I change var map = L.mapbox.map on click (mapbox.js)

Tags: javascript, onclick, mapbox

I have a base map set.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'wmarci.i6n42nl5', {
    fullscreenControl: true,
    fullscreenControlOptions: {
    position: 'topleft'
  }
}).setView([38.8929,-100.0252], 4);
```

How do I change it to then #2012 is clicked it changed that variable?

The following,

```
$('#2012').click(function(){
    map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'wmarci.hao88g0d')
});
```

doesn't seem to be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a map container is initialized, you'll have to remove this map in order to set another to the same container.

Try this:

```
$('#2012').click(function(){
    map.remove();//<<Here comes the magic!
    map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'wmarci.hao88g0d');
});
```

Comment: How do you write an if/else when element has class of foo to remove map, and initialize another map, else keep original initialization?